# What is dual read or dual write?

Tags: .net, azure

I'm watching [MVA video](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/service-fabric-patterns-and-practices-16925?l=NgldAdSGD_405167344) regarding how to hyper-scale web. At 10.20, the speaker mentioned about dual read and dual write. I tried to google about Azure or Microsoft or .Net dual read and dual write, still can't find the relevant information.

Appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: It is about reliability, keeping the system going when a data center fails.  Dual writes ensure that you'll have a backup center that can take over the job.  Dual reads help to detect inconsistency of the data between the centers.  This web site has it as well, you normally contact the server in New York.  If it goes offline then you'll get the one in Denver.  Although I think it is not sophisticated enough to allow users to continue asking questions.

Comment: @HansPassant could you provide the reference? I would be interested to know in detail.